# ElasticSearch: change field value using query in code

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have a code for editing records in ElasticSearch repository:

```
client.execute {
      update(id).in(indexName).script("ctx._source." + query)
}
```

and I don't know what string to give to `query` variable.
The index looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "lang": "ru",
    "deleted": false,
    ...
  }
]
```

I should change `deleted` to `true`

Comment: There's plenty of examples in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html).

Comment: @TomášLinhart thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right

```
"deleted = true"
```